# Python Turtle Trouble - ending for loop too soon

Tags: python, loops, random, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to build a Mondrian art creator that allows you to create any number of rectangles, each with a random size.  I am able to create the random size, but the trouble I'm having is getting it to create more than two random rectangle.

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.screensize(1000,1000)
turtle.setworldcoordinates(-500,-500,500,500)

piet = turtle.Turtle()
piet.speed(3)

#primary colors, red, blue, yellow
#piet.color(red,blue,yellow)

rectangles = int(input('How many rectangles should be drawn?'))
rectangle_w = int(input('What should be the max width of the rectangles?'))
rectangle_h = int(input('What should be the max height of the rectangles?'))

def mondrian(t,random_w,random_h):
    for number_r in range(1):
        for box in range(2):
            t.left(90)
            t.forward(random_w)
            t.left(90)
            t.forward(random_h)



mondrian(piet,random.randint(10,rectangle_w),random.randint(10,rectangle_h))

def repeat_mondrian():
    while mondrian(piet,random.randint(10,rectangle_w),random.randint(10,rectangle_h)) < rectangles:
        return False
repeat_mondrian()
```

Comment: Nice early program.  Unrelated to your issue, think about what this line of your code does, and what you intend by it:  `for number_r in range(1):`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `while` here. To call the function `rectangle` times, use a `for-loop`:

```
def repeat_mondrian():
    for i in range(rectangles):
        mondrian(piet,random.randint(10,rectangle_w),random.randint(10,rectangle_h))
```

---

Note that in Python, functions return `None` by default if the function ends without reaching a `return` statement. So the `mondrian` function always returns `None`.

So the condition

```
mondrian(piet,random.randint(10,rectangle_w),random.randint(10,rectangle_h)) < rectangles
```

is equivalent to

```
None < rectangles
```

which, in Python2, is always True since `None` is less than any number. In Python3, the comparison `None < rectangles` would raise a TypeError!

The reason why your code never drew more than one rectangle is because the `return-statement`:

```
while mondrian(piet,random.randint(10,rectangle_w),random.randint(10,rectangle_h)) < rectangles:
    return False
```

causes Python to exit `repeat_mondian` after the very first iteration in the `while-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

So unutbu you were right, but i found out that it makes an extra rectangle. So I subtracted 1 from the # of rectangles in the for loop. Thank you!

```
def repeat_mondrian():
    for i in range(rectangles-1):
        mondrian(piet,random.randint(10,rectangle_w),random.randint(10,rectangle_h))

repeat_mondrian()
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (maybe you don't have that privilege yet?)  Make sure you understand why you're making too many rectangles.  It's a common error that you will make many times over your career.

Comment: @zak, the extra rectangle comes from the call to `mondrian` that is *outside* the `for-loop`. Remove that one, and then you will not have to subtract one in `for i in range(rectangles-1)`.